# How many threads is normal in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, activity-monitor

I just rebooted my system and right now Activity Monitor is showing over 500 threads running. Before I rebooted it was over 900. Is that normal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That really depends on how many applications you have open and what Mac you have. I currently have 650 threads with minimal usage. As long as it doesn't affect your Mac's performance, it shouldn't be a problem.